# Hyperledger composer v0.19 with Fabric 0.11 zerotoblockchain-network.card installation issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am checking out https://github.com/rddill-IBM/ZeroToBlockchain

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The tutorial initially used composer v0.16 and olde fabric version. 
However post fabric upgrade to 0.11 - only composer v0.19 works. 
I upgraded to v0.19.0 using 
 `npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.0`

Post this upgrade, my ./buildAndDeploy on Chapter03 kept failing at
 -----> starting network
with card not found admin@zerotoblockchain-network.

So, I created a new card.

```
 ~/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer card create -n zerotoblockchain-network -u admin -p DevServer_connection.json -f /tmp/zerotoblockchain-network

~/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer card import -f /tmp/zerotoblockchain-network.card
```

I understand that DevServer_connection.json should not be used as it's getting used by the PeerAdmin file but I am a loss to which key file to use

Now, the buildAndDeploy fails at

```
      =====================================================
       -----> starting rest server v0.15 for admin@zerotoblockchain-network
       =====================================================
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
    at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:360:34)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean Hyperledger Composer `v0.16` and `v0.19` and Hyperledger Fabric `v1.0` and `v1.1`.

According to the release note [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases), you need to stick to Hyperledger Composer `v0.16` if you are using Hyperledger Fabric `v1.0`. To use Hyperledger Composer `v0.17` and beyond (up to `v0.19` at the time of writing), you need Hyperledger Fabric `v1.1`.

To install the latest version of Hyperledger Composer `v0.16`, you may use:

```
npm install -g hyperledger-composer@'~0.16'
```

Do the same step for `composer-cli` and `composer-playground` if you use them:

```
npm install -g composer-cli@'~0.16'
npm install -g composer-playground@'~0.16'
```